# ActiveMQ Artemis vs ActiveMQ Classic connection

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

Is there any difference between ActiveMQ Artemis connection configuration between `aplication.yaml`:

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=192.168.1.210
spring.artemis.port=9876
```

vs

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=secret
```

If you use only this dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I assume that `spring-boot-starter-artemis` allows you to connect via JMS, and that is `spring.activemq.XXX`, and if you want to connect in the Artemis approach then you use `spring.artemis.XXX` the bean will autocofigure.

But I am not sure

I read the [key differences](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration-documentation/key-differences.html) on this page.

Which one is better? For JMS (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) I can use CachingConnectionFactory, is it needed for artemis auto-configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `spring-boot-starter-artemis` that indicates you want to connect to an instance of [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which means you'll want to configure `spring.artemis.XXX` properties. Assuming you're using `spring-boot-starter-artemis` 2.7.0 (i.e. the latest) you'll want to use `spring.activemq.broker-url` as referenced in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.artemis), e.g.:

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=secret
```

The `host` and `port` properties you referenced were deprecated in favor of `broker-url` awhile back.

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.artemis) continues:

> By default, a `CachingConnectionFactory` wraps the native `ConnectionFactory` with sensible settings that you can control by external configuration properties in `spring.jms.*`:
>
> ```
> spring.jms.cache.session-cache-size=5
> ```
>
> If you’d rather use native pooling, you can do so by adding a dependency to `org.messaginghub:pooled-jms` and configuring the `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` accordingly, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> spring.artemis.pool.enabled=true
> spring.artemis.pool.max-connections=50
> ```

Whether you use `spring-boot-starter-artemis` with `spring.artemis.XXX` properties or `spring-boot-starter-activemq` with `spring.activemq.XXX` properties the underlying Spring components will use JMS to connect.

Comment: It makes more and more sense to me now. But there are still some doubts. When you make a dependeny only for:

spring-boot-starter-artemis

You can make two configuration one through BEAN like this with ActiveMQConnectionFactory:

Comment: `import org.apache.activemq.**artemis**.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory createCachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, user, password));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(sessionCacheSize);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
`

And the other through properties with autoconfiguration spring.artemis.XXX that will wrap CachingConnectionFactory.
Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about this.